# cloning zebra date picker moves the icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

so I am attempting to clone a div that has zebra date pickers in it. unfortunately the icon keeps sliding to the left on every clone.

run the snippet below and click clone a few times for an example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // assuming the controls you want to attach the plugin to
  // have the "datepicker" class set
  $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();

  $('#container').on('click', '.clonebtn', function() {
    const myTemplate = $(this).closest('.cloneMe');
    const clonedTemplate = myTemplate.clone();
    clonedTemplate.find('.Zebra_DatePicker_Icon').remove();
    $('#container').append(clonedTemplate);
    let datepicker = clonedTemplate.find('input.datepicker');
    datepicker.Zebra_DatePicker();
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra_datepicker@latest/dist/css/default/zebra_datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra_datepicker@latest/dist/zebra_datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="cloneMe" style="border:1px solid black;">
    <div style="padding: 10px;">
      <input class="datepicker" type="text" />
    </div>
    <button class="clonebtn">
  clone me
</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are cloning a modified DOM that has a lot of inline style already added with zebra. An idea is to remove all the inline style during the cloning and you will obtain the same layout each time:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // assuming the controls you want to attach the plugin to
  // have the "datepicker" class set
  $('input.datepicker').Zebra_DatePicker();

  $('#container').on('click', '.clonebtn', function() {
    const myTemplate = $(this).closest('.cloneMe');
    const clonedTemplate = myTemplate.clone();
    clonedTemplate.find('.Zebra_DatePicker_Icon').remove();
    clonedTemplate.find('*').removeAttr('style'); /* Added this */
    $('#container').append(clonedTemplate);
    let datepicker = clonedTemplate.find('input.datepicker');
    datepicker.Zebra_DatePicker();
  });

});
```

```css
.cloneMe {
 border:1px solid black;
}
.cloneMe > div {
 padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra_datepicker@latest/dist/css/default/zebra_datepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/zebra_datepicker@latest/dist/zebra_datepicker.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="cloneMe" >
    <div >
      <input class="datepicker" type="text" >
    </div>
    <button class="clonebtn">
  clone me
</button>
  </div>
</div>
```